# Total variation of real valued functions on a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

We can define the total variation of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ as in Evans and Garriepy's "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions" or in this Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation. I would like to use total variation for scalar functions on a manifold, but I have not seen it discussed anywhere. I have two questions.

1) How might we modify this definition so it makes sense on a manifold? I expect to at least need a Riemannian metric.

2) Say we've done number 1. In the Euclidean case, the total variation in the $C^1$ case is equal to $\int |\nabla f|$. Does the analog of this integral still capture total variation on an arbitrary Riemannian manifold? My intuition says it should in the flat case, but I should worry about curvature.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it all goes through unmodified - just replace the Euclidean norm with the Riemannian norm. Curvature shouldn't get involved since you're just dealing with first derivatives of scalars.

Comment: In that case, would the coarea formula still apply?

Comment: Certainly if $f$ is regular enough - see e.g. Ex III.12(d) of Chavel's *Riemannian Geometry 2ed*. The fact that he requires $f$ to be $C^{\text{dim} M}$ is interesting - I'm not sure whether this extra regularity is required or if it just makes the proof easier - I suspect the latter.

Comment: Looks like [this article](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Coarea.pdf) proves the co-area formula for a Lipschitz function.